# Math.Net Weighted Least Squares dimensions issue

Tags: math.net

I'm trying to run a univariate WLS - using `WeightedRegression.Weighted(X,y,W)` - and am getting the error message `Matrix dimensions must agree: op1 is 5836x1, op2 is 5836x1`. Whether I make Y a column vector or a matrix (with only one column) does not matter.

From the error message, you can see the matrix (or the vector and matrix) dimensions agree - both have 5836 rows and 1 column.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What are the dimensions of your weight matrix? I think it expects a diagonal matrix, so in your case 5836x5836.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Andrew. My weight matrix was simply a vector of weights - I will make it into a diagonal matrix.